# Why ContT doesn't deal with the inner monad?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

The bind strategy for `ContT` ignores the inner monad, in fact the code is the same as for `Cont`.

Following the analogy from other Monad Transformers I would have implemented it this way:

```
return x = ContT ($ (return x))
(>>=) x f = ContT (\k -> runContT x ((=<<) (\a -> runContT (f a) k)))
```

Then for example this expression:

```
do 
    x1 <- ContT (\k -> k [1, 2])
    x2 <- ContT (\k -> k [10, 20])
    return ((+) x1 x2)
```

Would result in `[11, 21, 12, 22]`

My question is what was the reason behind that design decision? Why was it implemented that way, which makes it very different from other Monad Transformers, note that the functor instance is:

```
fmap f m = ContT $ \c -> runContT m (c . f)
```

rather than:

```
fmap f m = ContT $ runCont $ (fmap . fmap) f (Cont (runContT m))
```

which is more or less the same as for other Monad Transformers, but the current implementation seems to break the functor composition, I mean since monads do not compose automatically we may have discussions about different bind strategies but for functors and applicatives it should always be the same and here it seems to be quite different. Was it a hack to get some code which represent more use cases working?

Even [IdentityT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.2.2.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html#IdentityT) works that way, but I read that the bind strategy for `Cont` is in fact the same as for `Identity`, so what about `ContT` and `IdentityT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(>>=)` doesn't need to deal with the inner monad (besides that it's not possible to implement it in a way you proposed, as chi showed), because we can just `lift` monadic values and get the desired semantics.

```
lift :: Monad m => m a -> ContT r m a
lift ma = ContT (ma >>=)
```

Or as it is in the standard [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html):

```
instance MonadTrans (ContT r) where
    lift m = ContT (m >>=)
```

Now we have

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

test :: ContT r [] Int
test = do
  x <- lift [1, 2]
  y <- lift [10, 20]
  return (x + y)

-- evalContT test == [11, 21, 12, 22]
```

In other words, with the standard monad instance for ContT we can already manipulate the current continuations *arbitrarily*, so alternative implementations could hardly buy us anything.

Comment: Thanks. I'm marking this as answered for now. But I'm happy to switch to another answer if someone provide more details

Comment: `ContT r m` is actually a monad even when `m` isn't. This is actually used in the `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` module: `ReadP` is basically `forall r . ContT r P`. `P` does have a `Monad` instance but not a valid one, but the `Monad` instance for `ReadP` is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Let's check the types for the proposed implementation of `(>>=)`:

```
> let foo x f = ContT (\k -> runContT x ((=<<) (\a -> runContT (f a) k)))
> :t foo
foo
  :: Monad m =>
     ContT r m (m a) -> (a -> ContT r m a1) -> ContT r m a1
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That should be `ContT r m a` to match the type for `(>>=)`.

Similarly for `return`:

```
> let bar  x = ContT ($ (return x))
> :t bar
bar :: Monad m1 => a -> ContT r m (m1 a)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There's an extra `m1` above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was more interested in the reason it was implemented that way than in a code review of my sample code. I want to know why that bind strategy was adopted. I don't think it was because of the types, the types are usually decided in function of the bind strategy, not the opposite. You can swap the order of the type variables but forget the details, the main question it's in the title.

Comment: @Gustavo If you want to `instance Monad m => Monad (ContT r m)` then the return and bind operation _must_ have exactly those types. Maybe your actual question is "why isn't `ContT r m a` defined as `(m a -> m r) -> m r`" or something similar that would allow your binding function? If so, you should be clear about it in your question since I thought it was about `ContT` as we know it (except for the bind/return), and not about a different monad transformer. If possible, propose a type you would use for `ContT`.

Comment: Thanks @chi. In fact I don't want anything ;) Looks like by providing more details I was misunderstood. I'm not proposing anything, may be I should delete my code. I just want to know why it was decided to work that way which is very different to the other monad transformers. There must be a good reason to break the analogy, specially with the Functor and Applicative.